# Guava.Objects.hashCode vs Java.Objects.hashCode

Tags: java, java-8, guava, hashcode

In Java 8 there is a class `java.util.Objects`, which contains `hashCode()` method. At the same time Google Guava 19 contains `com.google.common.base.Objects`, which also has `hashCode()` method.

My questions:

1. Is there any reason why should I prefer Guava's 19 `hashCode()` over Java's 8?
2. Can I completely rely on Java 8 `hashCode()` or it's better to stay with Guava?

Comment: Why do you think the Guava implementation would be better than the new built-in? Also, define "better".

Comment: This class is there since Java 7

Comment: Perhaps, Guava's hash is based on better/other hash-function?

Comment: like many other things, java inserts into the base classes features from guava or other libraries. This happened with Optional class that was first in guava and added to java8, many collection utils and more, and also hashcode. You can simply look at the source codes to see if there's a different implementation. In my mind- if you're using already the guava method - I wouldn't go into the trouble of migrating. if you don't and want to use this method- I prefer to use internal java when possible

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Guava's method predates' Java 7.

The Java method of the same name only accepts a single argument. But a sibling `java.util.Objects.hash()` accepts a variable number of arguments, like Guava's `Objects.hashCode()`.

If you're using Java 7 or later, you can use `java.util.Objects.hash(...)`. The [Guava documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object...)) notes this:

> Note for Java 7 and later: This method should be treated as deprecated; use Objects.hash(java.lang.Object...) instead.

If you're using Java 6 or earlier, you can use Guava's method.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer:

While `Objects.hash()` should be preferred to Guava in Java 7+ code, note the below (paraphrased) from Effective Java 3rd Edition by Joshua Bloch (Item 11):

> Unfortunately, `Objects.hash()` runs more slowly because it entails
>
> 1. array creation (*)
> 2. boxing and unboxing of any primitive arguments
>
> It is recommended for use only in situations where performance is not
>   critical.

(*) Indeed, `Objects.hash()` simply invokes another static method under the hood:

```
public static int hash(Object... values) {
        return Arrays.hashCode(values);
    }
```

**What you can do to counter this is to either**

1. cache the computed hash code instead of recomputing it each time 
   and/or
2. lazily initialize it.

(but also remember that premature optimization is the root of many evils).

**Alternatively:**

1. Simply use your IDE to generate it for you (saves time, but boilerplate code still there). In IntelliJ: `Code > Generate > equals() and hashCode()`
2. consider adding [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) as a dependency